# Material and Texture not applied to Plane in the 3D Viewport

Tags: texturing, materials

I am following some old tutorial about Point Tracking and I added a Plane to follow my finger together with Particles.

My problem now is what ever Material and Texture I create it doesn't seem to apply to my plane when looking in the 3D Viewport (I changed to a yellow color).

[image]

Also I don't see my plane when I render.

[image]

Being a beginner with Blender I am a little confused what is going on. Can someone point me in the right direction ?
And let me know if I didn't provide enough information about my scenario.

File Upload:
[image]

Comment: if u provide your blend file i can exactly tell what you have to do to achieve what you want

Comment: i just opened your file and see that: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhcPG.png ...so your plane is yellow....assuming you are a beginner: click on the plane in the outliner, then click on "." -> then you see the plane (in yellow)

Comment: Hmm, it does nothing for me. I am using a laptop, so not sure if I need Numpad keys or not.

Comment: Instead of „.“ you also go View - Frame selected

Comment: Ah ok, now I see it. Thanks. I wonder why my particles haven't changed to that color. Instead of white bubbles I was expecting this yellow ones :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here:

[image]

there are several buttons.

In the default settings you won't see material colors in the viewport shading and wireframe shading. (left 2 buttons of the 4)
But if you click on Material preview or rendered view you can see materials.

Comment: I tried that before, but it doesn't work. I switched to different layouts and nothing.

Comment: If you want I can provide you with the file. Not sure how.

Comment: Open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: Thanks. I added the uploaded link in the my question.